# Use https connection for Facebook Canvas App

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, https, pubnub

I'm actually developing a Facebook Canvas version of an app using PubNub, my problem is that Facebook is blocking all non-https connection, even PubNub send/receive message requests.

Is there anyway to tell to the PubNub SDK to use https version of the PubNub routes ?
I really don't need the security of an https connection for my PubNub messages.

Note: I'm using the AngularJS SDK.

EDIT: My application is using https connection, only pubnub keep using simple http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man when you develope in a facebook canvas is required the https in the iframe loaded, and by security all comunication in a https page all outcomming conection must be over a secure channel (Another ssl connections...).

Make  PubNub comunicate in a ssl channel, try this:

[PubNub Readme](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/blob/master/README.md#ssl-mode)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create Canvas Apps or Page Apps without https, you always need SSL.

Comment: I know that, my application already used https connection, the problem is that PubNub don't. He keeps requesting its servers with http connections which are blocked.

Comment: That´s a security feature of modern browser, there is no way around that - it´s a feature, not a bug ;)